# Why doesn't Rust infer the never type?

Tags: rust, type-inference, bottom-type

Consider this Rust code:

```
fn loop_forever() {
    loop {
        
    }
}

fn main() {
    let hello = if true { "Hello, world!" } else { loop_forever() };
    println!("{}", hello);
}
```

The return type of `loop_forever` is inferred to be `()`, so [compilation fails](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&code=fn%20loop_forever()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20loop%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20hello%20%3D%20if%20true%20%7B%20%22Hello%2C%20world!%22%20%7D%20else%20%7B%20loop_forever()%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%7D%22%2C%20hello)%3B%0A%7D) because that's not compatible with the type of `"Hello, world!"`. But the return type can be `!` instead, and if I write `fn loop_forever() -> ! {` instead of letting it be inferred, then [it works fine](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&code=fn%20loop_forever()%20-%3E%20!%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20loop%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20hello%20%3D%20if%20true%20%7B%20%22Hello%2C%20world!%22%20%7D%20else%20%7B%20loop_forever()%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%7D%22%2C%20hello)%3B%0A%7D). So why doesn't Rust infer this in the first place?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rust never infers a function's return type. If not specified it defaults to `()`. The inside of the function body cannot affect the function's signature.